# How to substitute partial powers?

Tags: python, sympy

I have an expression which contains terms like `expr = a**m * b**n` where `a,b` are symbols and `m,n` are integers. I want to use `expr.subs(a**i * b**j, 0)` to set the expression to zero if `a**i * b**j` is a factor of `a**m * b**n` (here `i,j` are integers too). This works in some cases, but not when only one of the symbols is used for the substitution:

```py
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> a, b = symbols('a b')
>>> (a**2 * b**3).subs(a**2 * b**2, 0)  # (1) works
0
>>> (a**2 * b**3).subs(a * b**2, 0)  # (2) works
0
>>> (a**2 * b**3).subs(b**2, 0)  # (3) does not work
a**2*b**3
>>> (a**3).subs(a**2, 0)  # (4) does not work
a**3
>>> (a**4).subs(a**2, 0)  # (5) works
0
```

I would like this substitution to work in all of the above cases and logically it should (since for example `a**2 * b**3` is equivalent to `a**2 * b * (b**2)` and thus the substitution `(b**2, 0)` should yield `0`). However, if using a single symbol in the substitution, it seems to work only for those cases where the expression contains the subs-term raised to a power; for example:

```py
>>> (a**2 * b**4).subs(b**2, 0)  # (6) works
0
>>> (a**2 * b**4).subs(b**3, 0)  # (7) does not work
a**2*b**4
```

This behavior seems a little odd since it works for `b**1` and also when artificially augmenting both, the actual expression and the subs-term, with some other symbol:

```py
>>> (a**2 * b**4).subs(b, 0)  # (8) works
0
>>> c = symbols('c')
>>> (c * (a**2 * b**4)).subs(c * (b**3), 0)  # (9) works
0
```

While I could use this last observation (augmenting expressions) as a workaround, it doesn't seem neither clear nor efficient.
Hence, is there another way to make the substitution work for all cases where the subs-term is contained in the actual expression?

---

```py
>>> sympy.__version__
'1.10.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if something is a factor of a product you can use `extract_multiplicatively`:

```
>>> expr = a**3*b**3*c
>>> 0 if expr.extract_multiplicatively(a*b**2) else expr
0
```

You could also use the `rem` function to see if the remainder is 0:

```
>>> rem(expr, a*b**2)
0
```

If your expressions occur within a larger expression, then these could be incorporated into a `replace` call, `expr.replace(...)`. If you are trying to ignore high-order terms in an expression you can just make a function to add the order of all symbol-based powers in a term:

```
>>> expr = expand((x + 1)**3*(y + 1)**2)
>>> def order(m):
...     return sum([degree(m, x) for x in m.free_symbols])
...
>>> expr.replace(lambda x: not x.is_Add,
...     lambda x: 0 if order(x)>2 else x)
3*x**2 + 6*x*y + 3*x + y**2 + 2*y + 1
```

Comment: These two approaches seem to be promising indeed. However, I don't see how I could combine them with `expr.replace` in order to apply the substitution to each term in a larger expression. Specifically, I have a larger expression which consists of various terms `coefficient * x1**p1 * x2**p2 * ... * xn**pn` added or subtracted where `coefficient` is a real number, `x1, ..., xn` are symbols and `p1, ..., pn` are integers. I want to truncate this expression to second order in `x1, ..., xn`, i.e. I want to remove all terms where `sum([p1, ..., pn]) > 2`. How would I solve this with `expr.replace`?

Comment: answer has been updated with a `replace` approach for that objective

Answer (score 0):

1. works, because a**2 = 0 is 0 * b**3 what leads to 0
2. a = 0 means a**2 = 0 -> 0
3. b**2 = 0 but b**2 is not in b**3, so it does not work
4. same issue as 3
5. a**4 is in a**2 so 0
6. same as 5 but with b´s
7. same issue as 3
8. b is in b**4
9. c = c so it comes to 0 because only symbols get replaced

Everything works like intended

Comment: I can't follow your logic. For example (2) nowhere I specified that `a = 0`; I did specify `a*b**2 = 0` instead. For (3) you claim that `b**2` *"not in*" `b**3` but this is exactly what I challenge: `b**3` is equivalent to `(b**2)*b` so `b**2` is a factor of `b**3` and I interpret "x (is) in y" as "x is a (multiplicative) factor of y". For (9) `c` *is* a symbol and it gets replaced together with `b**3` as a whole expression, i.e. `c*b**3`.

Comment: a is a symbol and becomes 0 because the b**2  only belong to b**2 a is separated